# Is it possible to modify a method inside `__init__`?

Tags: python, optimization

I want to create a simple log program. The problem occur when I was trying to insert console output feature.

My initial codes was like this:

```
import datetime

class LogOutput:
    def __init__(self, debugMode=False):
        self.isDebug = debugMode
        self.f = open(
                    'logs/log-{date:%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S}.txt'
                    .format( date=datetime.datetime.now()),"w+"
                    )
        self.f.write("            Test Loggings                \n")
        self.f.write("    Date: {date:%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S}       \n".format( date=datetime.datetime.now()))
        self.f.write("-----------------------------------------\n\n\n")

    @classmethod
    def debugModeConsole(cls):
        return cls(True)
    @classmethod
    def start(cls):
        "Set debugMode to False"
        return cls(False)

    def Write(self, output):
        self.f.write(output)
        if(self.isDebug):
            print(output)
```

I realize that this part where I used `if(self.isDebug):` is inefficient, and was wondering if I could do this only once, that is during class initialization, something like this:

```
def __init__(self, debugMode=false):
    self.isDebug = debugMode
    ...
    if(self.isDebug):
        self.Write()= (self, output) => {
            self.f.write(output)
            print(output)
        }
```

Comment: You can, just remove the `self` part: this is called a class variable. Also, is there a reason for you not to use the logging library instead?

Comment: @olinox14 Thank you, and yes, there is a reason, because I am new to python, and am trying to learn through coding a project instead from tutorial. And coming from C++ I ~~ab~~used processor macros a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can, kind of.

Long answer:

If I were in your shoes, I would do something like

```
class LogOutput:
    def __init__(self, debugMode=False):
        self.write = self.write_debug if debugMode else self.write_no_debug
    def write_no_debug(self, output):
        self.f.write(output)
    def write_debug(self, output):
        self.f.write(output)
        print(output)
```

But not before doing any profiling, because maybe your solution isn't as inefficient as you think.

Comment: Thank you... If I may ask, what is this called in python? Because all that can think of is `method overriding`

Comment: @SazeimSaheem I am not sure it really has a name. As always on method access, the descriptor protocol is used for turning the function as a class member into a method (for implicitly passing `self`), and an instance attribute is assigned then to the one or other method.

Answer (score 1):

The python equivalent of javascript arrow functions are `lambda` functions. lambda functions can be assigned to a variable, but `self` will not be automatically passed in, since it is not defined as part of the class. Additionally, only one statement is allowed in the "body" of a lambda function. So try this:

```
if self.isDebug:
        self.Write = lambda output: helper_func(output)
```

and elsewhere in the class:

```
@classmethod
def helper_func(output):
    self.f.write
    print(output)
```

There is a lengthy tutorial on python lambdas here: https://realpython.com/python-lambda/